# FCC Personal Portfolio stuck with two requirements

Tags: html, css

So I have trouble trying to complete these two requirements.

1. My portfolio should have a link with an id of profile-link, which opens my GitHub or FCC profile in a new tab.
2. The height of the welcome section should be equal to the height of the viewport.

I thought I would have already cleared them but somehow the script in codepen says I haven't. So I'm not sure if I did what I was supposed to.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```css
#projects {
  margin-top:1000px;
}

#navbar{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  position: fixed;
  
}
#welcome-section{
  height:100vh;
  font-size:100px;
}
#body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 #navbar {
    font-size:10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<nav id="navbar">
  <div id="logo">
    <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
  </div>
  <ul id="navlinks">
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body id="body">
<welcome id="welcome-section">
  <h1> Welcome! </h1>
</welcome>

<div id="projects">
  <a class="project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/imsmoothlikebutter/pen/BaQeWwO" target="blank"> Project example </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/imsmoothlikebutter" id="profile-link" target="blank">freeCodeCamp</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add following tag in your html code -

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

In  tag use target as "_blank" instead of "blank"

In @media query you need to specify what happens to specific html element when viewport size is as per your declared size for that @media query
ex.-

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 #navbar {
    font-size:10px;
  }
 #body{
    height:400px;
 }
}
```